# Enable OpenCL GPU Rendering on Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel Skylake GT2?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux, opencl

I know this is experimental technology and I shouldn't get my hopes up; I installed both the proprietary Intel OpenCL SDK (2016) and open-source Beignet (they don't seem to be interfering with one another) and devices appear under the OpenCL category when I run Blender 2.78 with

```
CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 blender
```

The Beignet drivers are giving me compilation errors, but the Intel render kernels work for CPU rendering only.  When I attempt GPU rendering ("Intel HD Graphics" option), the render will stop on the first tile and will not progress further. I get no errors; with the Supported feature set I only get the message "Device init success" and with the Experimental feature set, I get the list of successfully compiled kernels.  I have tried running as root with the same results.  After several minutes, I get the errors:

```
OpenCL error (Intel(R) HD Graphics): Hardware running slow or hung.
OpenCL error (Intel(R) HD Graphics): Out of resources.
OpenCL error (Intel(R) HD Graphics): Out of resources.
```

I have an Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) graphics chip alongside a quad-core Intel® Core™ i5-6300HQ CPU.

Perhaps it's time to get a dedicated GPU, but I'm wondering -- has anyone had success with this setup?